# How to add custom logs in Protractor test reports

Tags: protractor, report

I'm trying to add some custom logs to my protractor test report. I've app log file in my project folder which has the logs captured using log4js. I want these log entries to be shown in my test report as well. Currently I'm using chercher report. Since I'm a beginner to protractor, I'm not sure how to do this. Can anybody help me on this? Thanks in advance!

**spec.js**

fdescribe('Protractor Perfecto Demo', function () {

```
it('should pass test', function () {
  browser.reportingClient.stepStart('Step 1: Navigate Google');
  browser.driver.get('https://www.google.com'); //Navigate to google.com
  browser.reportingClient.stepEnd();
  //Locate the search box element and insert text
  //Click on search button
  browser.reportingClient.stepStart('Step 2: Send Keys');
  browser.driver.findElement(by.name('q')).sendKeys('PerfectoCode GitHub');
  browser.reportingClient.stepEnd();
  browser.reportingClient.stepStart('Step 3: Click');
  browser.driver.findElement(by.css('#tsbb > div')).click();
  browser.reportingClient.stepEnd();

});

//This test should fail
it('should fail test', function () {
  browser.reportingClient.stepStart('Step 1: Navigate Google');
  browser.driver.get('https://www.google.com'); //Navigate to google.com
  browser.reportingClient.stepEnd();
  //Locate the search box element and insert text
  //Click on search button
  browser.reportingClient.stepStart('Step 2: Send Keys');
  browser.driver.findElement(by.name('q')).sendKeys('PerfectoCode GitHub');
  browser.reportingClient.stepEnd();
  browser.reportingClient.stepStart('Step 3: Click');
  browser.driver.findElement(by.css('#tsbbbsdasd > div')).click();
  browser.reportingClient.stepEnd();
});

  afterAll(function(done){
      
      process.nextTick(done); 
  });
```

});

**conf.js**

var reportingClient;

exports.config = {
//Remote address
//   seleniumAddress: 'https://MY_HOST.perfectomobile.com/nexperience/perfectomobile/wd/hub',
directConnect: true,
//Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
capabilities: {
browserName: 'chrome'
// user: 'MY_USER',
// password: 'MY_PASS',
// platformName: 'Android',
//deviceName: '123456',
},

```
//Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
framework: 'jasmine',

// Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
// protractor is called.
specs: ['./tests/SignupAutomation_spec.js'],

// Options to be passed to Jasmine.
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,   // Use colors in the command line report.   
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000  // Time to wait in ms before a test fails. Default value = 30000
},

onComplete: function () {
    // Output report URL
    return reportingClient.getReportUrl().then(
        function (url) {
            console.log(`Report url = ${url}`);
        }
    );
},

onPrepare: function () {
    const Reporting = require('perfecto-reporting');

    reportingClient = new Reporting.Perfecto.PerfectoReportingClient(new Reporting.Perfecto.PerfectoExecutionContext({
        webdriver: browser.driver,
        tags: ['javascript driver']
    }));
    browser.reportingClient = reportingClient;

    var myReporter = {
        specStarted: function (result) {
            reportingClient.testStart(result.fullName);
        },
        specDone: function (result) {
            if (result.status === 'failed') {
                const failure = result.failedExpectations[result.failedExpectations.length - 1];
                reportingClient.testStop({
                    status: Reporting.Constants.results.failed,
                    message: `${failure.message} ${failure.stack}`
                });
            } else {
                reportingClient.testStop({
                    status: Reporting.Constants.results.passed
                });
            }
        }
    }

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(myReporter);
}
```

}

While running this I'm getting below error:

**An error was thrown in an afterAll
AfterAll JavascriptError: javascript error: end is not defined
(Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)
(Driver info: chromedriver=90.0.4430.24 (4c6d850f087da467d926e8eddb76550aed655991-refs/branch-heads/4430@{#429}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19042 x86_64)**

Comment: I guess there are many tutorials available online for this. On stack overflow we clear one's doubts and issues. So let us know what u tried so far and what issues you have faced. So that we can help you out with it .

Comment: I would look try a Google search to look for adding a custom Jasmine reporter. These will be injected in a plugin before the Jasmine runner starts.

Comment: @KSK, adding more details on the stuff that I tried so far.